# Ubuntu 16 VLAN interface doesn't work (bond and non-bond)

Tags: networking, server

I created the next configuration for VLAN,

```
###
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0.100 inet static
iface eth0.100 inet static
address 192.168.56.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 1921.168.56.1
vlan-raw-device eth0
```

During boot or when I try to manually trigger ifup eth0.100 I see next error:

Cannot find device eth0.100

The same happens when I try to manually configure through ip command

Thanks

---

Looks like the problem is all VLANs are being named as renameX interfaces :/
I do use links for eth matching with mac addresses.
Is there a workaround with VLANs? We have 2 VLANs on each server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm running something very similar, with both VLANs and multiple subnets and the syntax is close (eth0.100:3).  You can put both eth0 and eth0.100 in the same 'auto' line and you don't need the vlan-raw-device if eth0 is in the base interface name like eth0.100.

Try assigning a static address on another network (fake, if needed) and see if eth0.100 lights-up.